# Prove $x^{a+b} + y^{a+b} \le 2$ for $x^a+ y^a = x^b+ y^b$ $(a \ne b)$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, inequality, exponential-function

> Let $a$, $b$   distinct positive numbers and $x$, $y>0$ such that
> $$x^a+ y^a = x^b+ y^b.$$
> Show that $x^{a+b} + y^{a+b} \le 2$.

Notes:

1. It is easy to show that $x^b + y^b\le 2 $.  Indeed,  assume that $a< b$. We have

$$\left(\frac{x^a + y^a}{2}\right)^{\frac{1}{a}} \le  \left(\frac{x^b + y^b}{2}\right)^{\frac{1}{b}}$$ and so

$$\left(\frac{x^a + y^a}{2}\right)^{\frac{1}{a}- \frac{1}{b}}\le 1$$

2. If $x^c+y^c\le 2$ for some $c> 0$ then $x^d+ y^d \le 2$ for all $0\le d \le c$. The argument is similar to the one above.
3. The exponent $a+b$ is the largest possible ( see above).
4. I have seen a problem about $x^2 + y^2 = x^3+ y^3$ on this site.

Any feedback would be welcome!

Answer (score 2):

*Remark*: This is related to
[this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4006824/show-this-inequality-xn1yn1-ge-xnyn).

WLOG, assume that $a < b$.

**Fact 1**: Let $u, v, r > 0$ be real numbers. Then
$$\frac{u^{r+1} + v^{r+1}}{u^r + v^r} \ge \left(\frac{u^{2r+1} + v^{2r+1}}{2}\right)^{\frac{1}{2r+1}}.$$
(The proof is given at the end.)

By Fact 1, letting
$r = \frac{a}{b - a}, u = x^{b - a}, v = y^{b - a}$, we have
$$\frac{x^{b} + y^{b}}{x^a + y^a} \ge \left(\frac{x^{a + b} + y^{a+b}}{2}\right)^{\frac{b - a}{a + b}}$$
which results in
$x^{a + b} + y^{a + b} \le 2$.

We are done.

---

*Proof of Fact 1*:

Since the desired inequality is symmetric and homogeneous, assume that $v = 1$ and $u \ge 1$.

Taking logarithm, it suffices to prove that
$$\ln (u^{r+1} + 1) - \ln (u^r + 1) \ge \frac{1}{2r+1}\ln \frac{u^{2r+1} + 1}{2}.$$
Let $f(u) := \mathrm{LHS} - \mathrm{RHS}$. We have
$$f'(u) = u^{r-1}\cdot \frac{ru^{2r+2} - (r+1)u^{2r+1} + (r+1)u - r}{(u^{r+1} + 1)(u^r + 1)(u^{2r+1} + 1)}.$$

Let
$$g(u) := ru^{2r+2} - (r+1)u^{2r+1} + (r+1)u - r.$$
We have
$$g'(u) = r(2r + 2)u^{2r+1} - (r+1)(2r+1)u^{2r} + r + 1$$
and
$$g''(u) = 2r(r + 1)(2r + 1)u^{2r - 1}(u - 1).$$

Since $g''(u) \ge 0$ on $u \ge 1$ and $g'(1) = 0$, we have $g'(u) \ge 0$ on $u \ge 1$. Since $g(1) = 0$, we have
$g(u) \ge 0$ on $u \ge 1$.
Thus, we have $f'(u) \ge 0$ on $u\ge 1$.
Since $f(1) = 0$, we have $f(u) \ge 0$ on $u \ge 1$.

We are done.

Comment: Hi, it seems that the problem is tightly related to the fact $1$. What is the motivation behind the fact? Actually, I cannot think of any clue or hint to guess such an inequality! [+1]

Comment: @RezaRajaei Thanks. First, $x^{a+b} + y^{a+b}\le 2$ is written as $\left(\frac{x^{a+b} + y^{a+b}}{2}\right)^{\frac{1}{a+b}} \le \left(\frac{x^b + y^b}{x^a + y^a}\right)^{\frac{1}{b - a}}$. Second, recently, I encounter the inequality $\left(\frac{x^5 + y^5}{2}\right)^{1/5} \le \frac{x^3+y^3}{x^2+y^2}$ which makes me connect them.

Comment: I see. Thank you!

Comment: Hi, a very nice solution!  But I think the problem is in fact very much the same as the other one, I would rather delete it since it is a duplicate.

Comment: @orangeskid It seems not obvious that it is a duplicate. I did not remember that question immediately when I saw your question.

Comment: Hi, I added a solution to the other problem based on your idea. It uses the fact that for $f(x) = \log \cosh x$ we have $f'''< 0$ on $(0, \infty)$.